# Can't execute python script that imports cv2.so from php

Tags: php, python, opencv

i am trying to run a python script for image proccessing from php

php script

```
<?php
echo exec('echo $PATH ');
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin");
echo "<br>";
echo exec('echo $PATH');
echo "<br>";
echo exec('whoami');
echo "<br>";
echo exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/wordspot/uploads/editimage1.py /var/www/html/wordspot/uploads/test.jpg 2>&1'); ?>
```

python script

```
import sys,getopt
import numpy as np
import cv2

imname=str(sys.argv[1])
print imname
img=cv2.imread(imname,0)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite(imname,thresh1)
```

while on terminal when executing "php test.php" it works (i run it as root)

on browser i get this output

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
apache
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i think that the import cv2.so is causing this error (it runs for example on hello world python example)
What can i do to make the opencv libraries visible from apache user?

Edit
Solution: adding the path of the library in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf` and `executing ldconfig -v`
 changed the error to `"ImportError: libopencv_core.so.3.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied"`

After disabling SELinux with `setenforce 0` it worked. (This is will not survive a reboot, SELinux needs to be disabled from in `/etc/selinux/config` and change to `SELINUX=disabled`, or providing the correct permissions in SELinux to allow access to the library.)

Comment: $PATH is for executable binaries. there's an LD_PATH for libraries. you need to check that path.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `libopencv_core.so.3.0` located? If it's in `/usr/local/lib`, try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this before executing the program:

```
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib");
```

Comment: this didn't work. i exequted however ldconfig -v after setting the path on /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf and i have a new error now, similar with the above. the new error is
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.3.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied

Comment: Solved, i needed to disable SELinux as well.

Comment: @DiamantatosParaskevas Sir, I need your help. My python script not working in symfony but works fine in terminal